# Unable to set up a Windows Hello PIN

Tags: windows, windows-hello

I am unable to set up Windows Hello using a fingerprint or my face, because when I go to set up the PIN it always fails with the same error code: `0x8028008a`.

I'm using Windows 10 Pro 21H1.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, The error code `0x8028008A` maps to `TPM_20_E_TYPE` [1]

You should ensure that the Trusted Platform Module of your device is clear and ready to use. In my case, Windows said it was ready for use but I still had to clear it to resolve the issue.

To clear the TPM:

1. Windows+R, type in "tpm.msc"
2. Click on "Clear TPM..." on the sidebar

The system will reboot automatically. You may need to follow some instruction during boot depending on the setup of your system.

**Warning:** clearing your TPM can result in data loss. If BitLocker is enabled, ensure you have a copy of your recovery key.

[1] https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-error-codes-6